# how to instantiate a dsp slice in virtex 6?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

i am working on a vhdl code (virtex 6). where i need to do number of multiply and accumulate operation. how do i use dsp slices for this(an in the instantiation and inference). Are there any examples which can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Look here in ISE:

`Edit > Language Templates > VHDL > Device Primitive Instantiation > Virtex 6 > Arithmetic Functions`

A detailed user guide for the DSP slice is available from the [Xilinx Website](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug369.pdf). It explains the function of every port on the entity.

If you want a better answer, you need to give *far* more detail in your question.

Comment: thanks.But i am exactly stuck there. what should to assigned to those ports and how to use them in the code.